# int property coming through as a decimal? causing error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a line of code that I am receiving the following error:

> The 'OPSPackageID' property on 'Series50Order' could not be set to a
>   'System.Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value
>   of type 'System.Int32'.

I receive that error on this line:

```
var order = series50.Orders.Where(s => s.EnrollmentCardNumber == id.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

It is odd because the error seems very straight forward but when I look in my Series50Order model it is already set to an int:

```
public int OPSPackageID { get; set; }
```

I tried making it an Int32 also and still the same error:

```
public Int32 OPSPackageID { get; set; }
```

The field in SQL server is numeric and there are no decimals.  So why am I receiving this error?

Comment: @DavidL but in SQL server it is a numeric field and there are no decimals.  They are always whole numbers.

Comment: What is the underlying *type* of the column in SQL Server?

Comment: What is the code for the constructor for Series50Order class?  Or did you let it default?

Comment: @DavidL, I use the default.

Comment: @DavidL, I was talking about the constructor, I use the default.  In SQL server I mention that in the OP, it is numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the following [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx), numeric and decimal column types in SQL Server are synonyms and can be used interchangeably.  This means that they are both precision types and CANNOT be deserialized into an integer, regardless of whether or not precision is used and regardless of whether or not the values stored are whole numbers.

As a result, you have two choices:

a. Update the target property to be a decimal.

```
public decimal OPSPackageID { get; set; }
```

b. Manually convert or cast the incoming column to int every time you use it, which is not recommended since it will lead to loss of precision when ***coming from*** the database and may result in Overflow when ***storing in*** the database.